# Angular changes to HTML don't apply once the browser is refreshed (ASP.Net Core 2.0 API)

Tags: angular, development-environment, asp.net-core-2.0

I have tried both running the project through VS and VS Code but none worked. The Development environment's already been set. I have tried with multiple browsers but no luck. If I change anything in the HTML, it doesn't get reflected in the browser.

[image: Development Environment]

[image: Developer tools]

[image: LaunchSettings]

Any ideas?

Comment: try the hard refresh please .Hit ctrl + f5 and see

Comment: Every time I stop the project and run it up again it doesn't take the changes to effect. Whatever changes I make into the HTML pages don't get reflected after the run, it just shows the standard Hello World template. It's weird ... must be loading up a static template from somewhere.

Comment: it is loading from the cache. Did you try the hard refresh?As a workaround check in private window, it should work.

Comment: Yes, I did, didn't work though.